# Why doesn't this `:execute` command work?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, line-numbers

I was looking at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/519129/135943) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, and I thought I could write an answer for it using Vim.

I ran the following for a quick test, and was surprised to find it didn't seem to do anything.  I was expecting it to replace the first number on the first line with one less than the number of lines in the buffer.

```
:execute '1s/^[0-9]\+/' . line('$')-1 . '/'
```

Here is the text I had in the buffer at the time:

```
5 10
sample_1 gaatatccga
sample_2 gaatatccga
sample_3 gaatatcgca
```

Why didn't the `:execute` command shown above replace the `5` with a `3` as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` has the same precedence as `+` and `-`

`'1s/^[0-9]\+/' . line('$')-1 . '/'` is the same as `('1s/^[0-9]\+/' . line('$')) - 1 . '/'`—it's `string - number . string`, which is not what you want.

To solve your problem:

```
:execute '1s/^[0-9]\+/' . (line('$')-1) . '/'
```

- `:h expr-.`.
- `:h expression-syntax`.